# Dynamically create chef resource from string

Tags: ruby, dynamic, resources, chef-infra

Trying to see how best to call some ruby code dynamically from text within a string.

The following creates a directory with chef:

```
directory /tmp/test do
  mode "755"
  owner me
  group me
  action :create
end
```

If the text "directory" was contained in a variable, I would like to use this to call the same code without an expicit if statement.  I don't know enough about ruby/chef to do this.

Current approach:

```
if action == "directory"
  directory /tmp/test do
    ...
  end
end
```

Desired approach (something to the effect of):

```
"#{action}" /tmp/test do
  ...
end
```

Comment: You can use `declare_resource(:directory, "/tmp/test") do <normal resource block> end` and can also use `build_resource` with the same syntax.  the difference is that the former puts the resource on the resource collection (declaring it) while the latter will only return the resource and you have to explicitly call actions on it yourself.  The Chef DSL internally uses declare_resource (which uses build_resource) behind the scenes.  They're probably not documented well, but are supported, and are preferred over (e.g.) passing `provider` to the package resource.

Comment: @lamont I tried using this with a custom resource located in the definition tree.  It didn't work but the accepted answer did.

Comment: what is "custom resource located in the definition tree"?  you mean a definition (they aren't "custom resources")?  and if you can use the recipe DSL but can't use declare_resource/build_resource that should be reported as a bug (and i can't quite see in my head how that fails to work...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`directory` in the Chef DSL is a method call. You can dynamically call methods in Ruby using `send`. In this case it would look like:

```
send(action, '/tmp/test') do
  ...
end
```

This is really not recommended for the most part though, it will rapidly lead to hugely unreadable code and I'm not sure what situation you would have where the `...` in there would actually be interchangable. Remember that your code should be readable first, and repeating things is fine if they aren't likely to change that often.

Comment: While I agree there is a trade off between legibility and writing many lines of boilerplate code.  Hence the need for comments.

Comment: I would need a more complete example to advise further, but there aren't a ton of places where you would have shared boilerplate inside the resource in such a way that this structure would be useful.